# Delete Object from CoreData (error)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'd like to delete an object from core data. I tried this code but it's not working. What's wrong? I'm working with Swift and Xcode 6.1.1.

Code:

```
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var daten = [TaskModel]() //CoreData Entity

    managedObjectContext!.deleteObject(daten[indexPath.row])
    appDelegate.saveContext()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TaskModel")
    daten = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [TaskModel]
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Right)
```

Comment: If the code is as written, there's nothing in 'Daten' because you've just initialized it as an empty array of TaskModels. If your code is different then as written, please break it out.

Comment: It says: `fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`daten` is an empty array.

Therefore, `daten[x]` will crash.

In your case, `x` is `indexPath.row`, but it will crash with any value.
If you try to access an element of an empty array by index, you will get the above error.

To get an object from your fetched results controller and delete it,

```
let task = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as TaskModel
self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(task)
self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.save(nil)
```

The standard implementation of the fetched results controller from the Xcode template will take care of updating your table view automatically, you even get animation for free.

If you are **not** using a `NSFetchedResultsController`, stop here and refactor.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer. How can I get this working (Delete a UITableViewCell from a UITableView and delete the entry in the CoreData Library)?

Comment: That is a separate question. You should accept the answer. I have included a solution for your second question as well.

Comment: But I don't get a fade out animation.

Comment: Set the animation in the call to `deleteRows...` to `UITableViewRowAnimationFade` or similar (use auto-complete).

Comment: I set this after the 3 lines you've posted: `        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)`but it's not working.

Comment: I cannot troubleshoot your issue because I do not have enough information. Best to open another detailed SOF question.